# Maxi Pad flushed down the toilet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, toilet, clog

I accidently flushed a rolled up maxi pad down the toilet 14 days ago at a friend's house while on vacation. We stayed at their house for 7 days and it was clogged with the pad the first day we stayed there. It got unclogged with a plunger moments after it was flushed and hasn't clogged for the rest of the vacation. Does that mean the pad made it through or should I still be worried about it? People have been using the toilet too and it's flushing fine. I'm worried it might back up everyone's waste and flood or something if it's still in the pipe.

Comment: It's probably fine. Stop doing that.

Comment: I didn't mean too but is it possible it could still be in the pipes and back up the toilet or would that have happened by now?

Comment: I'm not sure how possibly could you unclog it, but since there is no problem for a while it appears that you have fixed it.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it, so it isn't worth worrying about. Assuming a normal sewer or septic-tank system, it'll probably be fine unless there are other things contributing to a blockage... so the blame won't be entirely yours even in that case. This really is a case of "just learn from the mistake and try not to do it again,"

Answer (score 1):

It is completely impossible to determine if the maxipad is still in the house plumbing or not with the information given or without a first hand evaluation of the sewer system.

The only ways to be really sure are one of these:

1. Run a cleanout snake down the sewer to check if it can snag the pad and pull it back out.
2. Run a remote inspection camera down the sewer to visually inspect the pipes to make sure the pad is still not present.

What choices do you have?

Either do one of the above steps or just wait, keeping your fingers crossed, and hope for the best whilst being prepared for the possible nasty mess.

Comment: sadly I cant do any of these because it happened at a friend's house and they're in a different state so if something happens I can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Entara - Well if they do not know about it yet make sure to tell them about what happened.

Comment: So you're saying it's still possible it could back up after 14 days? Most people said it should be fine and I would think if there were signs of it being clogged still they would've happened by now. The toilet was working fine after we left their house. It hasn't backed up into the tub or anything.

Comment: @Entara - I am not saying that it will or will not backup due to the pad stuck someplace in the pipe. The point I am making is that there is NO way to be sure. You came with the question as to whether you should worry about it. I point out that to alleviate your worry the only way to be sure is to investigate and inform. Anything else from this viewpoint is pure guess work.

Comment: Oh golly.  This answer would be improved by providing some likelihood of whether there is a problem — if many people have used the fixture and over fifty flushes have gone through it with no problem, isn’t the likelihood of a clog nearly Zero?

Comment: @whiskeychief - If there was ever a problem it was probably over four years ago. Since there was never any further feedback from Entara we will probably never know. The comments in the answer still apply. There was no way to be 100% certain of the sewer line state with the information provided. Statistical elimination has the habit of proving the  0.3% case as still possible.

Comment: Hmph, I didn’t notice the date on the post.   Sorry to bother you.